# Filling all input fields

Tags: html, angular

There is a markup:

```
<div class="scroll">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>ISBN</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let book of bookService.bookList">
        <td><img src="../../{{book.ImagePath}}" width="100" height="150"></td>
        <td>{{book.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{book.Author}}</td>
        <td>{{book.Year}}</td>
        <td>{{book.ISBN}}</td>
        <td>{{book.Price}}</td>
        <td>{{book.Count}}</td>
        <td>

            <input type="text" name="Count" [(ngModel)]="Count">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success" (click)="onAdd(book, Count)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The last column looks like this:

[image]

The problem is the following: when filling one `TextBox`, all the `TextBoxes` in the column are filled.

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Tried to give unique names to text fields and to thrust this cell in `form`, but all the same did not work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give unique name to the input field using angular template

```
<input [name]="'count' + i" >
```

Where `i` is the index from the `*ngFor`

But I think the major issue you have is that you need to bind `book.Count` instead of just `Count`

In latter case you'll have one variable called `Count` and you bind the same  variable to all of the input fields. You need to attach the variable to the book itself so it is unique.

Answer (score 2):

All your inputs have the same `[(ngModel)]="Count"` and the same name so if you update one, all of them will be updated

You can fix that if you have an array of count instead. So it will be something like

```
<tr *ngFor="let book of bookService.bookList; let i = index">
...
<input type="text" [name]="'count' + i" [(ngModel)]="count[i]">
```

Comment: This work for input, but when I use [(ngModel)]="count[i]" I get table like this https://imgur.com/a/0xzp1eP

Comment: Can you show me your html ? There is no reason that changed the render.

Comment: Html is in the question

Comment: I guess it's the css then, changing the model or name shouln't have any impact on the render

Answer (score 2):

People are giving you the HTML way, I'm giving you the Angular way : `trackBy` functions.

```
*ngFor="let book of bookService.bookList; trackBy: book.Name"
```

This one should work but I've never tested it.

The one should work in any case :

```html
*ngFor="let book of bookService.bookList; trackBy: customTB"
```

```js
customTB(item, index) {
  return `${index}-${item.Name}`;
}
```

Comment: Does angular rebuild the DOM if you add a property to the element? Why do you think the `trackBy` is a solution here?

Comment: @doodoroma yes it does, and it is a solution because that's the solution I've been given a year ago when I asked the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same name for your inputs. 
To fix this, you can add an id populate by the index of the loop ***ngFor**

Try this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let book of bookService.bookList; let i = index">

<input type="text" name="Count_${i}" [(ngModel)]="count">
```